# Comparison issues between varchar and int columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm having some weird comparison issues between my `varchar` column and my `int` column.

#### My Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `organization_m` (
    `organization_recid` VARCHAR(36) CHAR SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT 'uuid - unique identifier'
    ,`organization_id` INT (16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`organization_name` VARCHAR(100) CHAR SET utf8 NOT NULL
    ,`organization_sequence` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`license_recid` VARCHAR(36) CHAR SET utf8 NOT NULL
    ,`country_recid` VARCHAR(36) CHAR SET utf8 NOT NULL
    ,`contact_number` VARCHAR(20) CHAR SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
    ,`address` VARCHAR(200) CHAR SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
    ,`organization_url` VARCHAR(100) CHAR SET utf8 NOT NULL
    ,`notes` VARCHAR(500) CHAR SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
    ,`is_active` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`created_on` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
    ,`modified_on` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
    ,`created_by` VARCHAR(50) CHAR SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`organization_recid`)
    ,UNIQUE KEY `organization_id`(`organization_id`)
    ,UNIQUE KEY `organization_sequence`(`organization_sequence`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 8622 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `organization_m`
--
LOCK TABLES `organization_m` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `organization_m` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `organization_m`
VALUES (
    '017811ce-becf-4395-a780-9bde07c4a692'
    ,1268
    ,'123'
    ,NULL
    ,'cd224237-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978'
    ,'cd2276db-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978'
    ,NULL
    ,'somewhere'
    ,'/api/v1/somewhere'
    ,NULL
    ,1
    ,'2015-02-23 13:43:22'
    ,'2015-02-23 13:43:22'
    ,NULL
    )
    ,(
    '9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799'
    ,1275
    ,'cards'
    ,NULL
    ,'cd224237-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978'
    ,'cd227f0c-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978'
    ,NULL
    ,'somewhere to nowhere'
    ,'/api/v1/cards'
    ,NULL
    ,1
    ,'2015-02-27 16:17:25'
    ,'2015-02-27 16:17:25'
    ,NULL
    )
    ,(
    'b469e572-86a4-4019-96c5-a6df964e520b'
    ,9
    ,'123'
    ,1143
    ,'cd224237-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978'
    ,'cd227f0c-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978'
    ,NULL
    ,'New York'
    ,'OSMO1143'
    ,NULL
    ,1
    ,'2015-01-20 13:45:40'
    ,'2015-01-20 13:45:40'
    ,NULL
    );
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `organization_m` ENABLE KEYS */;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

---

#### My Select Query

```
SELECT * FROM organization_m WHERE organization_id = '9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799' OR 
organization_recid = '9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799';
```

---

#### My result set

[image: Query Resultset]

---

#### Problem

I expected only one result that is the organization with rec_id of `organization_recid = '9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799';`. I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior, but is there a way I can get around this?

---

#### Other DB Information

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1710
Server version: 10.0.16-MariaDB-1~wheezy mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
```

Comment: column: 'organization_id'  - Are you aware that '9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799' is not a valid integer format? As a hex string and converted to binary it will not be held accurately in an ''integer'.  It may be more useful to store it as a binary string. [The BINARY type is similar to the CHAR type, but stores binary byte strings rather than non-binary character strings.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/binary/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB will automatically cast the string you passed as `organization_id` into an integer (since that is its type).

Casting `9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799` into an int equals 9. (It stops at the first char, because the 2nd char is not an integer). You can see the casting by executing the following query :

```
select CONVERT('9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799', SIGNED);
```

This is why you are getting the 2nd row with `organization_id = 9`.

So basically, your query is being interpreted as :

```
SELECT * FROM organization_m WHERE organization_id = '9' 
OR  organization_recid = '9f14dc52-23c7-4567-8ec9-90aa45c87799'
```

I dont know what is the context of that code, but you should always filter / sanitize values, when used in a query.

Take control. If you expect an integer, then make sure it is one. Otherwise, you will end up with a strange behavior / bug.